# Index Out Of Bound Exception in TextWatcher

Tags: android, textwatcher

I am using a TextWatcher to change the text of an EditText while typing. The string appends the new/replaced text to the old text then displays it. I want to display only the new/replaced text. I am trying to keep the index of the "previous" text and display only the new text that has been replaced. I am not sure if that's the right way of doing it, may be I am doing it totally the wrong way, that is why it is giving me an index out of bound exception. Could anyone please help. For example I type a, and next time when I type b the text displayed in the text box is aab and not ab, I want to remove this redundancy. Below is my code: And also how can I insert a new line character if the characters for a line exceed a limit e-g 10, characters after 10 chars should be display in the next line

```
tw = new TextWatcher()
{           
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,int start,int count, int after){} 

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
    {                               
        txtData.removeTextChangedListener(tw);
        txtData.setText(s.toString().replace("\n", "*"))
        txtData.addTextChangedListener(tw);
    }
};
txtData.addTextChangedListener(tw);
```

Comment: what is it that you want to achieve? atm every letter you write will be handled individually. i assume you want to handle the charsequence currently in your textview. that would be s. you dont have to call getText() on txtData which is the edittext the textwatcher is attached to i assume

Comment: Thanks Daniel for your reply. I have made changes to my code according to your suggestion but the problem remains. I want to remove the redundant/repeated chars and insert a new line after n number of characters. For example if I type the letter a, it is displayed in the edittext but when I try to type the next letter, it appends the previous text to the next/new text for example a and then aab and then aabaabc then aabaabaabc but I just want abc to be displayed in the edittext, is there anyway I can get rid of the redundant text? and insert a \n say after 10 characters in the edittext?

Answer (score 0):

i havent tried this code, as i just made this up on a texteditor.

this should add a newline every 10 signs to the text. im not entirely sure if it counts \n as a sign so, you might want to check on that. in case it does count, you will have to make a little more complex if block :)

```
tw = new TextWatcher()
{           
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,int start,int count, int after){} 

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
    {
        if (s.toString().length()%10 == 0) {                               
            txtData.removeTextChangedListener(tw);
            txtData.setText(s.toString() + "\n");
            txtData.addTextChangedListener(tw);
        }
    }
};
txtData.addTextChangedListener(tw);
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH DANIEL it does work now, it does go to the new line but after every 9 characters, not 10 characters, also it still repeats the (9) characters of the first line and add the new ones until the line ends. A line can have a total of 26 characters and I wanted it to be limited to just 10. Your solution does work perfectly except for the first line and that it limits a line to 9 characters instead of 10. Any idea why? Thanks once again as you have solved the main problem.

Comment: I just changed this line **s.toString().length()%1 == 10)** with this line **s.toString().length()%11 == 0)** and it works for 10 characters now. Not sure why, the first line is still problemtic. That's the output **1234567890123456789012345-(next line) 678901-(next line) 2345678901-(next line) 2345678901 ... and so on**

Comment: i would have to make a project to try this myself, might look into it later on :)